# mod_rewrite - add path to REQUEST_FILENAME variable

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond application/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule (.*) application/public/$1 [L]
```

I want to make expression:

- If file `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` **doesn't exist** AND if file `application/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` **exists** do rewrite

Example results:

- /style.css = /application/public/style.css
- /gfx/logo.png = /application/public/gfx/logo.png
- /index.php = /index.php
- /Welcome = /index.php?input=Welcome (it's working)

What is proper code for this expression? I think i need to change line:

```
RewriteCond application/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

But i have no bloody idea how...

Full .htaccess listing:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule style,(.+).css tmp/merged/css,$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule script,(.+).js tmp/merged/js,$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond application/public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule (.*) application/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?input=$1 [L,QSA]
```

*(sorry for my english)*

Comment: i think i need to use %{REQUEST_URI} as well, but i have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found small workaround, but it's not elegant solution :(

```
RewriteEngine on

# Access to files in ./application/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) application/public/$1 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule application/public/(.*) $1 [DPI]

# Main rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?input=$1 [L,QSA,DPI]
```