# Redirect to existing file/folder if it exists in specific dir or go to index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder `App\ressources` that contains all the images, javascript library of the website.

What i'm trying to do is to redirect to the existing image/js or go to the index.php file that will handle the request and get the current module/controller/action.

So i made this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond App/ressources/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond App/ressources/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ App/ressources/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
```

It shoud not be difficult but "debuging" is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked for [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878931/mod-rewrite-add-path-to-request-filename-variable) but i didn't get an answer.

Here is my workaround:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) App/ressources/$1 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule App/ressources/(.*) $1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     # missing line, see comments
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L,QSA,DPI]
```

Basically we redirect everything (what doesn't exists as file) to App/ressources and if it still doesn't exist we redirect it back to / root dir. Then we redirect it to index.php.

1. If file not exists redirect to App/resources/
2. If file still not exists redirect back to root /
3. If file still not exists redirect to index.php

Comment: i understand what you have done, but it does not actually works, i get redirect to index.php even if the file exists. Adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]` before the last line seems to works.

Comment: Nop :) in fact the last rewrite rule redirect anything (no matter what was made in top lines) to index.php. So the ´RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]´ break the rewriting if the file exists.

Comment: Oh sorry i was coping it from my page and i didn't select one line - "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f " - check my edited answer. Now should be fine.

Comment: Ok, it works fine, and whitout the first line too. Is it neccessary ?

Comment: True, first line **is not** neccessary :)